# Why hasn't Netbeans added support for JDK-9 in the stable release yet?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, java-9

Netbeans 8.2 stable release does not work with JDK 9. You can't even open a project.

It's been 5 months since the release and they still haven't fixed the ***issue***. The ***development*** release does not have this problem, though.

So why aren't they fixing the bug when Netbeans is the recommended IDE from Oracle? **IntelliJ IDEA** does not have this issue.

Comment: Just ask them: https://netbeans.org/about/contact.html

Comment: We don't **know** and we're not the **support** for **NetBeans**.

Comment: How do you know they are not fixing the "bug"?

Comment: I tested and seems that Netbeans 8.2 with Java 10 working fine.

Comment: I hate to say this but, imho, NetBeans is **dead**. I had been a fan of it for years. Then, all this time have passed since the "donation" to Apache Foundation and the team is still struggling to deliver the very basic stuff (a decent Web support, for example). Also, most of the plugins are not compatible, etc. Meanwhile, IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse, among others, are adding features that might take forever until NB having them. That's sad, but I can't see it in another way, at this moment. I would be glad if somebody here has a different perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetBeans development is moving to the Apache Foundation. Currently it's an incubating project. See here for more information:

- http://incubator.apache.org/projects/netbeans.html
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/How+to+Participate

It's a tremendous amount of work to move a project. I believe the intent is to have NetBeans "graduate" out of incubation status first and then to release Apache NetBeans 9 with JDK 9 support. See links for updated status and schedules.

If you pull the NetBeans sources from Apache and build it, the result will support JDK 9 just fine. You can also poke around on the incubation site and find current development builds. (I'm not including a direct link because things are likely to change, and because these aren't GA builds.)

Comment: Just to add a couple of updates since your post: (1)  [Apache NetBeans 9.0 RC1](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90-rc1.html) was released today. (2) NetBeans 9.0 will also support the use of Java 10.

Answer (score 0):

In July 2018, Netbeans released an Apache Netbeans IDE 9.0 that is supported Java 9 & 10

Visit this link to download it

https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/

Answer (score -2):

Java 9 will be forward compatible yes. Reverse may or may not be true since Java 10 is now a rolling release cycle.

Basically if you think Netbeans with 9 and up your pretty much screwed for now. Give Apache 10+ years and we'll have the support. Till then consider some alternatives, there's always Atom and Eclipse.

Basically Java 9 is the Vista or Windows 8 of the bunch, its dead Jim!